# Differences between hosting options for SharePoint apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When we create a new app in Visual Studio, we are given the option to select an hosting model:

[image]

What are the differences between the various models?

Comment: It is totally dependent on how you will host your app, and what you want to do with your app. Microsoft has guidelines here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179887.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren - edited. Now it should be at least answerable.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, sure but it is still a fairly broad question. Without any information about what the app i supposed to do, all we can do is make an abstract from my link above

Comment: @RobertLindgren: actually - an abstract was just what I had in mind. Should at least give some quick info to cover the basics and then leave to the user further research.

Comment: I believe this blog post will address your question about the [basic difference between SharePoint Hosted App and Provider Hosted App](http://sharepointbag.com/blog/6/decision-making-develop-sharepoint-hosted-app-or-provider-hosted-apps/).

Answer (score 5):

So, a quick introduction of the different hosting options. It is really based on your requirements which one you should / need to choose.

*Note that it is possible to mix the different patterns as well*

All quotes and images from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179887.aspx):

**SharePoint-hosted App**

> Start with the simplest option: SharePoint-hosted apps, or apps where
>   all components are hosted on either an on-premises or Office 365
>   SharePoint farm. SharePoint-hosted apps are installed on a SharePoint
>   2013 website, called the host web. They have their resources hosted on
>   an isolated subsite of a host web, called the app web. It’s important
>   to know the difference between host webs and app webs.

[image]

**Provider-hosted App**

> Provider-hosted apps for SharePoint include components that are
>   deployed and hosted outside the SharePoint farm. They are installed to
>   the host web, but their remote components are hosted on another
>   server.

[image]

**Autohosted App (Now Deprecated!)**

> Autohosted apps for SharePoint are cloud-hosted apps whose remote
>   components are provisioned and deployed for you on Windows Azure. As
>   with a provider-hosted app, an autohosted app for SharePoint can
>   interact with a SharePoint website but also uses resources and
>   services that are located on a remote site that is hosted by Windows
>   Azure. The SharePoint 2013 installation provisions and deploys these
>   resources for you.

[image]

So, there you go! Now you should have enough info to determine which option to choose.

Comment: BTW, the MSDN article Robert referenced is the first hit in a Google search for "Differences between hosting options for SharePoint apps"

Comment: That's why a hecitated to even answer this question :)

Comment: But your the reputation hoarder in you got the upper hand, heeeeeey ;) ?

Comment: Haha you got me there @CameronVerhelst!

Answer (score 0):

As a default I would choose SharePoint hosted.  If you can't live with the restrictions on hosting the app on SharePoint, then go for either autohosted which will put it in the cloud for you and still have some restrictions or Provider hosted where you'll have to source you own server to host it on but have full control.