# Which is the main differences between sharepoint apps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

Can anyone explain me the differences between sharepoint apps:

SharePoint-Hosted;

Provider-hosted;

Sharepoint-hosted;

do these all apps need to configure store in sharepoint?

Comment: find here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/78090/21421